# date_trunc attribute not found

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am creating a glue job that will read in information from s3, perform a query, and output the results.  The query to be run looks something like this:

```
SELECT 
  date_trunc('hour', hourly_report.time) as hour, 
  sum(cost) as costs FROM table 
FROM hourly_report
GROUP BY 1
```

I loaded the data into a `DynamicFrame`, created a `DataFrame` `df`, and created a temp view of the data.

```
df.createTempView("hourly_report")
```

I then try and run a query on the view

```
spark.sql("SELECT date_trunc('hour', hourly_report.time) as hour, sum(cost) as costs FROM table FROM hourly_report GROUP BY 1")
```

This causes an error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Undefined function: 'date_trunc'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 7"
```

This seemed strange, but I tried to get around this by using a udf to do the date_trunc rather than using the sql date_trunc function:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf
spark.udf.register("date_truncate", lambda x: sf.date_trunc('hour',x), TimestampType())
spark.sql("SELECT date_truncate(hourly_report.time) as hour, sum(cost) as costs FROM table FROM hourly_report GROUP BY 1")
```

This causes a different error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'date_trunc'
```

What is the correct way to perform a `date_trunc` operation on a timestamp column, is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: What version are you using? `date_trunc` is only available in 2.3 or above.

Comment: Ah, I just checked, Glue only supports 2.2.1, that is the problem.

Comment: The solution is that you'd have to write your own `udf`. What are you trying to do? There may be another way.

Comment: Just trying to group data by date + hour.  I think I can make a pretty simple udf using  unix_timestamps, shouldn't be a problem

Comment: There's also [`pyspark.sql.functions.hour`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.hour). So you could create an hour column, then cast the timestamp as a date and group by both. That should be faster than using a `udf`